# RequireJS - r.js 'name' property vs. 'mainConfigFile' property

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

Using RequireJS, we have a build.js config file used for the r.js optimizer. My config looks like the following:

```
({
    "baseUrl": "./public/static",
    "name": "app/js/main",
    "mainConfigFile": "./public/static/app/js/main.js",
    "out": "./public/static/app/optimized/optimized.js",
    "paths" :{
        requireLib : 'vendor/require'
    },
    "include": 'requireLib'
})
```

the "include":'requireLib' line includes the require.js source in the optimized build, which is nice.

But I am confused about the 'name' property - it seems like we would always want the name property to be the same as the "mainConfigFile" property. In what case would you want to specify a different value for the name property than the mainConfigFile property?

As you can see, the values are the same for my config, there's only a path difference:

```
  "name": "app/js/main",
  "mainConfigFile": "./public/static/app/js/main.js",
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js